Excel Pivot-Table calculated fields with if statement return wrong results
In a simple Excel Pivot table the calculated fields return wrong values. Tested on Excel 2007 and Excel 365.
For comparing purposes I've added the columns Analysis and Develpement with IF statment in the Excel table.
What I would expect is that it should be Analysis = CFAnalysis and Develpement = CFDevelpement.
Do you have any ideas why the calculated fields behave like this?

